# Validate a Go struct field only if it is populated

Tags: go

I'm using this library to validate my Go struct.
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10

How do I validate a field only if it's populated? For example, I have an optional phone number field in one of my structs. If the user has provided this value, I would like to validate it using E.164 format.

```
Phone string  `validate:"e164"`
```

I searched for "optional" tag but couldn't find one.

Comment: https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/omitempty/ hope this helps

Comment: I understand that the validator team is reusing the omitempty terminology originally from json structure but I personally feel that omitempty in this case sounds non-natural. optional would be much better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`omitempty`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Omit_Empty) tag.

```golang
Phone string  `validate:"e164,omitempty"`
```

Answer (score 17):

As library documentation stated about [Multiple Validators](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Multiple_Validators),

> Multiple validators on a field will process in the order defined.

As @Flimzy described above, you can use [omitempty](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Omit_Empty) to validate optional fields on structs, but `omitempty` should come first in the list. Otherwise it is validated and got an error.

```
Phone string `validate:"omitempty,e164"`
```

Simple proof of code is below, you can run on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3ZrX7zaPc56)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    sv := validator.New()

    res := Response{}
    err := sv.Struct(&res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err) // no error
    }

    res2 := Response2{}
    err = sv.Struct(&res2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err) // error
    }

}

type Response struct {
    Phone string `validate:"omitempty,e164"`
}
type Response2 struct {
    Phone string  `validate:"e164,omitempty"`
}
```